# How do I add more vmtypes to euclytpus 3.4.2

Tags: eucalyptus

I am using eucalyptus 3.4.2 and I need to add more "vmtype" definitions. Where or how do I add definitions to the vmType screen?

Answer (score 0):

Eucalyptus supports [modification of existing types](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/4.1.0/index.html#euca2ools-guide/euca-modify-instance-type.html), and [restricting the visible types](https://eucalyptus.atlassian.net/browse/EUCA-6971) via policy but as of version 4.1 does not support additional vmtypes.

Comment: The link provided goes to the euca 4.1.x documentation main page (since HP took over) - could you explain a bit more about the commands in question in your answer?